Naive notion of connectedness of metric spaces
In a book on metric spaces I'm currently reading the section on connectedness is prefaced with this naive notion of connectedness one might have:

A metric space $(X,d)$ is not connected, if there are two nonempty
subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ such that $X = A \cup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

According to the author this would mean that every metric space with two or more elements were connected.
Is this correct? Shouldn't this mean that every such space were not connected since one could always find two disjoint subsets satisfying the quoted requirements?
Edit: The author obviously made a little mistake there. It should of course be that every space with two or more elements were not connected when applying this naive notion of connectedness.

Yeah, they must have meant to say every space with two or more elements would not be connected.

@peek-a-boo This is a preliminary 'intuitive' notion of connectedness, not the formal definition. The author probably included it to show that it fails.

@peek-a-boo No, I'm not. As I said, the author uses this naive notion about connectedness one might have to show that it doesn't make sense to define it like that.

ah I see, this is a preliminary notion. Ok so if we took this to be our notion of “not connected”, then you’re correct every metric space with more than two elements would be not connected… but we obviously don’t want such a silly definition. Hence, we modify it to the standard one by adding the word “open”. If the author said “every metric space with two or more elements were connected”, then that’s a typo.

@peek-a-boo Thanks. There are two editions of this book and in both this error can be found, which made me doubt myself a little.

you could always email the author :)

@peek-a-boo I could try, but if he answered, that would be a quite a sensation. ;-)
